# Can we lock screen in Windows Phone 7 or 7.1 emulator?

Tags: sdk, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7-emulator

I am writing some Windows phone APPs on VS2010 (WP7.1 SDK) and intend to use the lock screen function. As I know, we can press 'F12' to lock screen on WP8 emulator. I don't know whether we can lock the screen on WP7 or WP7.1 emulator. I am looking forward to your reply. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope, Win phone 7.0 emulator it is not possible.

Win Phone 7.1 emulator it is possible:
Here is MSDN link about that
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662945%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

In that above link they put Windows Phone OS 7.1 it the list (at top).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The VS2010 is impossible, no matter the OS is WP7 or WP7.1.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately in the emulator that comes with VS2010 this is not possible.

But you can develop for WP7.1 in VS2012 and use the emulator from VS2012 that supports locking the screen.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. You are right! No matter WP7 or WP7.1, the VS2010 is impossible.

Comment: So why did you accept the other answer, when my one is correct?